# How to extract data from table2 which is closest to the DATE FIELD of table1?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have following two table Diagnose & Exercise 
I would like to extract Exercise date closest to the Diagnose_Date and it should be 1 row from exercise table.

I have tried left join with DATEDIFF function in where condition

```
SELECT D.ID,D.Diagnose_Date,D.Type1,D.Type2,E.Exercise_Date],E.Field1,E.Field2,E.Field3
FROM Diagnose D
LEFT JOIN Exercise E
ON D.ID=E.ID
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,[Diagnose_Date],[Exercise_Date]) BETWEEN -30 AND 30
```

any help would be very helpful

Thanks in Advance

---

Diagnose Table

```
------------------------------------------
ID     Dignose_Date     Type1    SubType1    
------------------------------------------
1      10/01/2010       01       1.1
2      20/02/2012       02       2.2
3      30/03/2013       01       1.2
------------------------------------------
```

Exercise Table

```
------------------------------------------
ID     Exercise_Date  Field1  Field2  Field3
------------------------------------------
1      01/01/2010        x       y      z
2      10/02/2012        a       b      c
2      01/04/2012        e       f      f
3      01/03/2013        x       y      z
3      05/04/2013        a       b      c
3      01/06/2013        x       y      z
------------------------------------------
```

Expected Result should be :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID  Diagnose_Date  Exercise_Date Type1 SubType2  Field1  Field2  Field3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   10/01/2010     01/01/2010     01    1.1         x       y        z
2   20/02/2012     10/02/2012     02    2.2         a       b        c
3   30/03/2013     05/04/2013     01    1.2         a       b        c
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks Luigi for re formating! I dont know how you did it

Comment: Is there any relationship between the two dates, or can they be any number of days apart? In your example, the Exercise_Dates all fall before the Diagnose_Dates. Is this how the data actually behaves?

Comment: Hi, They can be any number of days apart( before or after Dignose_date),  but i need the very first one closest(before or after Diagnose_date) to the diagnose_date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in a CTE, for each diagnose get the smallest time interval between the diagnose date and all the exercise dates associated with that diagnose.

```
WITH MIN_DATES_CTE(ID, DATE_DIFF)
AS (
    SELECT ID, MIN(ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,[Diagnose_Date],[Exercise_Date])))
    FROM Exercise E
    INNER JOIN Diagnose D ON D.ID = E.ID
    GROUP BY E.ID
)
```

Then, join Diagnose and Exercise by ID and the smallest time interval

```
SELECT D.ID,D.Diagnose_Date,D.Type1,D.Type2,E.Exercise_Date],E.Field1,E.Field2,E.Field3
FROM Diagnose D
LEFT JOIN Exercise E ON D.ID = E.ID
INNER JOIN MIN_DATES_CTE ON MIN_DATES_CTE.ID = E.ID
WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,[Diagnose_Date],[Exercise_Date])) = MIN_DATES_CTE.DATE_DIFF
```

Comment: Cool... that's the CTE version of my answer, which I like better in my opinion coz it's cleaner with CTE.

Comment: Hi This seem like a good idea but only one issue is Min function here, for example Exercise_Dates are(01/01/2002,01/01/2013) and  Diagnose_Date(01/01/2012) then min function will display 01/01/2002  because the difference is -3650(-ve number!!)..... how do i pickup minimum difference even it is -ve number? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Abu Use ABS. I updated my answer with `MIN(ABS(DATEDIFF(..)))` and `WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(..)) = MIN_DATES_CTE.DATE_DIFF`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're just matching ANY single diagnose entry with ANY single exercise entry based on their dates being closest to each other.

Here's my line of thinking:
Do a full `JOIN` on diagnoses and exercises, order by absolute date difference, ascending.

```
SELECT
    D.ID,
    D.Date,
    E.ID,
    E.Date,
    ABS(DATEDIFF(day, D.Date, E.Date)) Diff

FROM Diagnosis D, Exercise E
ORDER BY Diff
```

You'll get a result like this:

```
ID  Date        ID  Date        Diff
3   2013-03-30  5   2013-03-25  5
2   2012-02-20  2   2012-02-10  10
3   2013-03-30  4   2013-03-01  29
2   2012-02-20  3   2012-04-01  41
3   2013-03-30  6   2013-06-01  63
1   2010-10-01  1   2010-01-01  273
3   2013-03-30  3   2012-04-01  363
2   2012-02-20  4   2013-03-01  375
2   2012-02-20  5   2013-03-25  399
3   2013-03-30  2   2012-02-10  414
2   2012-02-20  6   2013-06-01  467
1   2010-10-01  2   2012-02-10  497
1   2010-10-01  3   2012-04-01  548
2   2012-02-20  1   2010-01-01  780
1   2010-10-01  4   2013-03-01  882
1   2010-10-01  5   2013-03-25  906
1   2010-10-01  6   2013-06-01  974
3   2013-03-30  1   2010-01-01  1184
```

Now you can see the dates that are closest to each other, with the number of days they are far.

Of course, you won't use this, but from this list, you can select the first one:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    D.ID,
    D.Date,
    E.ID,
    E.Date,
    ABS(DATEDIFF(day, D.Date, E.Date)) Diff

FROM Diagnosis D, Exercise E
ORDER BY Diff
```

Now you can plug this statement in a `LEFT` join, so you can singly select a date matching another.
Like this:

```
SELECT
    fD.ID,
    fD.Date,
    fE.ID,
    fE.Date
FROM
    Diagnosis fD
    LEFT JOIN Exercise fE
        ON fE.ID = (SELECT TOP 1 E.ID
                        FROM Diagnosis D, Exercise E
                        WHERE D.ID = fD.ID
                        ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(day, D.Date, E.Date)))
```

Which gives the result:

```
ID  Date        ID  Date
1   2010-10-01  1   2010-01-01
2   2012-02-20  2   2012-02-10
3   2013-03-30  5   2013-03-25
```

Comment: Beemer, add a ROW_NUMBER function and you can totally get the smallest date difference by ID:     `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DIFF ASC) AS ROW_NUM`  Then in the WHERE clause, add `WHERE ROW_NUM = '1'`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I need only those date having closest Diff which could be before or after Diagnose_Date. In yoour result for ID = 3 Diff should be 5

Comment: @rwking, I think it's the same effect if you just `SELECT TOP 1` from the inner `SELECT`, so you don't have to do `WHERE ROW_NUM = 1`, etc.

Comment: @Abu, yes, D.ID=3 matches the date for E.ID=5, at a difference of 5 days.  So, basically use the answer from @GarethD's which uses the same line of thought, but with `OUTER APPLY`. I'm keeping this answer as a thought process.

Comment: Actually, @GarethD's answer still gives inaccurate results.  So, I posted my implementation, and I believe it works well according to how I've comprehended your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OUTER APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT  d.ID, 
        d.Diagnose_Date, 
        d.Type1, 
        d.SubType1, 
        e.Exercise_Date, 
        e.Field1, 
        e.Field2, 
        e.Field3
FROM    Diagnose d
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 Exercise_Date, Field1, Field2, Field3
            FROM    Exercise e
            WHERE   d.ID = e.ID
            AND     DATEDIFF(DAY, d.[Diagnose_Date], e.[Exercise_Date]) BETWEEN -30 AND 30
            ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, d.[Diagnose_Date], e.[Exercise_Date])) 
        ) e;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/653fd/1)**

I have done more testing on this and found that a method using `ROW_NUMBER()` is the most efficient:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  d.ID,
            d.Diagnose_Date,
            d.Type1,
            d.SubType1, 
            e.Exercise_Date,
            e.Field1,
            e.Field2,
            e.Field3,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.ID ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,[Diagnose_Date],[Exercise_Date])))
    FROM    Diagnose D
            LEFT JOIN Exercise E 
                ON D.ID = E.ID
)
SELECT  ID,
        Diagnose_Date,
        Type1,
        SubType1, 
        EID = ID,
        Exercise_Date,
        Field1,
        Field2,
        Field3
FROM    CTE
WHERE   RowNumber = 1;
```

I have compared this with my first solution and the answer with the most upvotes for comparison. The results are as follows:

**OUTER APPLY**

```
Cost relative to batch: 34%
--------------------------------------------------
Table 'Exercise'. Scan count 3, logical reads 3
Table 'Diagnose'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1
--------------------------------------------------
Total. Scan count 4, logical reads 4
```

**SELF JOIN WITH AGGREGATES (Highest voted so far)**

```
Cost relative to batch: 51%
--------------------------------------------------
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0
Table 'Exercise'. Scan count 2, logical reads 4
Table 'Diagnose'. Scan count 2, logical reads 2
--------------------------------------------------
Total. Scan count 4, logical reads 6
```

**ROW_NUMBER()**

```
Cost relative to batch: 15%
--------------------------------------------------
Table 'Exercise'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3
Table 'Diagnose'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1
--------------------------------------------------
Total. Scan count 2, logical reads 4
```

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/653fd/14)**

So the `ROW_NUMBER` solution has the lowest IO statistics, and the lowest estimated cost

Answer (score 0):

Using only standard SQL:

```
SELECT D.ID, D.Diagnose_Date, D.Type1, D.SubType1, E.Exercise_Date, E.Field1, E.Field2, E.Field3
FROM Diagnose D
LEFT JOIN Exercise E
ON E.ID=D.ID AND
   E.Exercise_Date=(SELECT MAX(Exercise_Date) FROM Exercise WHERE Exercise.ID=D.ID AND Exercise.Exercise_Date<=D.Diagnose_Date)
```

Comment: That actually doesn't give the correct result.  This matches `'2013/03/30'` with `'2012/04/01'`, instead of `'2013/03/01'`